# Process doesn't terminate after Just-In-Time

Tags: swig, jit

I have a cpp SWIG dll (.pyd).
I set a hard-coded breakpoint using `__debugbreak()` or `assert(0)`.
JIT pops a window to select a debugger. Two scenarios:

1. I close it. The process terminates.
2. I choose vs2019 and resume the running and exit as usual or terminate it. The process *seems* to end/terminate fine.

In both cases, the dll file is locked. When I use LockHunter, it lists a python.exe process. If I terminate it, then the lock is released. Before termination, process explorer shows that the process consumes memory.
Even after termination, the process is still listed in process explorer ("dead" zombie)?

---

My current hack to deal with this:

```
    print( 'Killing leftover python.exe processes that are locking _pyconfstruct.pyd' )
    for p in psutil.process_iter():
        if p.name() != 'python.exe':
            continue
        if p.status() != psutil.STATUS_STOPPED:
            continue
        #mem = p.memory_info()
        #print( p.name(), p.pid, p.status(), mem.rss )
        
        fl1 = r'c:\prj\confstruct\Debug\_pyconfstruct.pyd'
        fl2 = r'c:\prj\confstruct\Release\_pyconfstruct.pyd'
        try:
            #opened_files = str(p.open_files()) # slow and doesn't list dlls
            #print( opened_files )
            #if fl1 in opened_files or fl2 in opened_files:
            if 1: # just kill all zombies
                #print( '%s (%d) is locking _pyconfstruct.pyd; killing it' % (p.name(), p.pid) )
                p.kill()
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: If a python process is spawned, a child process is created. When destroyed, child processes always first becomes zombies before they are removed from the resource table. If you refresh the process explorer after killing the parent process, it should disappear.

Comment: I don't mind about the list, I mind about "the dll file is locked", and I can't build a new file until releasing the lock.

Comment: AFAIK a DLL is always locked by the process using it and you need to wait until it is released before replacing the DLL. Copying won't help you, since then the copying will be blocked. Using linux, you don't have these problems

Comment: You can automate things little to make life easier for you. This guy has made a VS extension in VB for attaching to a process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879324/how-do-i-attach-a-debugger-to-other-process-than-i-start-in-visual-studio-2017